# Saving/Reading BigInteger RSA keys to/from file

Tags: rsa, biginteger

I am trying to implement RSA using Big integers i can currently encrypt and decrypt fine but I need to be able to take the 2 lots of 2 BigIntegers n, e  and n, d of any Bit length up to 2048 and then some how save them to files named publicKey.txt and privateKey.txt . and then be able to read it in later. does anyone have any ideas for this.

would like to somehow save them like this so i can separate them into their 2 parts on reading them in using the , as the separator

publicKey.txt
n,e

privateKey.txt
n,d

Answer (score 0):

[RSA standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#appendix-A) defines [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) encoding for serializing private and public keys for transferring and storage. This format is a standard for cryptography software.